# SQLite dropped table not deleted

Tags: sqlite

In the `sqlite3` command line tool I dropped a table:

```
sqlite> DROP TABLE tableName;
```

It's a pretty big large table, so I would expect the sqlite file size to drop considerably. However, it hasn't changed at all.

What is the proper way to purge this table from the database completely?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The size of the file does not shrink when you delete a table in SQLite, you have to explicitely ask for it.

More info in the FAQ : http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q12

There are also some options to configure your database to have auto-vacuum enabled, you can find more info in the documentation of the `VACUUM` keyword here : http://www.sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html and the `PRAGMA` option here : http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_auto_vacuum

Comment: `VACUUM` does the trick, thanks! I somehow glimpsed over the FAQ on this issue :)